# Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of functions $E\to \mathbb{R}$ and suppose $E= \cup _{k=1} \;E_k$ for some sets $E_k$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of functions $E\to \mathbb{R}$ and suppose $E= \cup _{k=1} \;E_k$ for some sets $E_k$.  Suppose there is a function $f:E→\mathbb{R} $ such that $f_n→f$ uniformly on each $E_k$. Decide, with justification, if this implies that $f_n→f$ uniformly on $E$.

Is this statement is true..if  it is not true under what conditions the statement is true..can any help me please

Comment: For some “countable” sets $E_k$?

Comment: Not ture. an easy counterexample: $E=[0,1)$, $E_k=[0,1-\frac{1}{k}]$ and $f_n(x)=x^n$.

Comment: If $E$ is compact and $E_k$ is open for any $k$, then it is true. Is this you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

No, $(0,1]=\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=2}\left[\dfrac{k-1}{k},1\right]$ and $f_{n}(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}\chi_{[(k-1)/k,1]}(x)$ and $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$.